# Why does the first Season of Naruto have different Openings at the same time?

Tags: naruto

I've just been reminded of this from reading another question. For the first Season of Naruto (before the Chunin Exams) i've seen 3 openings.

- [Southen Cross 10's Toasted TV](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oZy9Q07qCYQ) (Dubbed - Zabuza's blood spurt from Haku and Kakashi being blind-sided by shuriken are black and white freeze frame. Naruto Poison scene is normal)
- [Cartoon Network](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=GGgj0QJnicg) (Dubbed - no censor as far as i know)
- [DVD](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=v2w699fJsAQ) (Dubbed - No Censor)

i suspect also the 4Kids version which for the Naruto Poison scene, Naruto is complaining about dropping his lunch, may also have a different opening however i actuly have never seen that (however i hear it notorious since it changes so much)

i am wondering why there are so many different openings for the same episodes?

NOTE: the Naruto Poison Scene is after they fight the 2 Water Ninja and Naruto makes that speach of not running away after extracting the poison with a Kunai. Kakashi then says something like

> Ahh Naruto, that was cool how you took out the poison and all, but if you don't treat the bleeding soon, your going to die. *pause* it's a good idea to stop the bleeding now

EDIT: all 3 openings i have seen occur for the same episodes, ie. Episode 2 on the DVD has one opening, the same episodes on Cartoon Network and Toasted TV has different openings.

Answer (score 4):

Generally, when it comes to anime, OPs are switched out every season (12-13 episodes/weeks) or so. This is also the reason why 2-season anime series mostly have 2 different OPs, and single-season anime(s) only have 1 OP.

Since Naruto's 1st season has 35 episodes ([according to Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_Naruto_episodes_%28season_1%29)), it makes sense that there are 3 different openings: the 1st season of Naruto is a roughly-3-season show, meaning that there will be 3 different openings.

If you meant "Why not forget about having different OPs in the first place?" as your question, it's hard to answer. It could be that production studios might want to inject some variety into the series, so that people don't get bored of watching the same opening 10, 20, or even 30 times.

Comment: sorry, i didn't make it clear (thought i did), all 3 openings appears for the same episodes rather than the normal switch we see over the course of a series, see my Edit

Comment: In that case, it could just be regional differences (or the tolerance a distributor has for anything "offensive." An easy comparison would be if 4Kids acquired an anime. You bet that they're going to change anything they may find doesn't fit the target audience, which is (most likely going to be) a completely different target demographic than the original creators intended.